# GraphQL query to cross reference data

Tags: graphql

Please find a basic simplified problem and a question below:

### Monopoly Example

**Data Types:**

USER

- name
- houses (one-to-many)

STREET

- name

HOUSE

- street (one-to-one)

Note that in my data model there is no reference between user and streets (maybe monopoly wasn't the best example -.-)

**Question:**

A user can have several houses on different streets. How can I query a list of streets that a specific user has houses on?

Wanted Result:

```
{
    "data": {
        "User": {
            "name": "The Hat",
            "streets": [
            {
                name: "Bow Street"
            },
            {
                name: "Oxford Street"
            },
            {
                name: "Park Lane"
            },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching relational data like that is typically handled by having nested fields in your query. The ability to traverse the data graph in a query is one of GraphQL's biggest benefits.

In general, [this article about GraphQL APIs](https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/designing-powerful-apis-with-graphql-query-parameters-aing7uech3) is a helpful resource to understand how it works.

Let's look at some different possible queries.

## Query a list of streets that a specific user has houses on

```
query {
  allStreets(filter: {
    house: {
      user: {
        id: "user-id"
      }
    }
  }) {
    name
  }
}
```

Here we make use of [a relational filter](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/filtering-by-field-xookaexai0/#relation-filters) passed in as an argument to query the streets that are related to a hours that is related to a specific user, which results in:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allStreets": [
      {
        "name": "Bow Street"
      },
      {
        "name": "Oxford Street"
      },
      {
        "name": "Park Lane"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

We can see that we get back a list of streets. We could also include the house field in the `allStreets` query to obtain that information as well.

## Query a specific user object and a list of streets that it has houses on

```
query {
  User(id: "user-id") {
    name
    houses {
      street {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here we specify a user by id, so the top-level object of the result is a single user object. Additionally, we are getting back a list of streets that user has houses on:

```
{
  "data": {
    "User": {
      "name": "The Hat",
      "houses": [
        {
          "street": {
            "name": "Bow Street"
          }
        },
        {
          "street": {
            "name": "Oxford Street"
          }
        },
        {
          "street": {
            "name": "Park Lane"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What's notable is that the structure of the response follows the structure of the query precisely.

Comment: So graphQL is smart enough to understand the relation between: User -> House -> Location ?

Comment: I'm sorry! I did not follow the described data model correctly. Let me update my answer :)